# why fd between ancil_send_fd(send fd) an ancil_recv_fd(receivefd) is different?

Tags: c++, c

this is lib ancillary test, why parent_process send 1,2, but child_process receive is 3, 5?

follow the code, this is test in lib ancillary:

```
void child_process(int sock)
{
    int fds[3], nfds;

    //rece fd is 3,5
    nfds = ancil_recv_fds(sock, fds, 3);
    if(nfds < 0) {
        perror("ancil_recv_fds");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void parent_process(int sock)
{
    int fds[2] = { 1, 2 };

    if(ancil_send_fds(sock, fds, 2)) {
        perror("ancil_send_fds");
        exit(1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I guess this thing called "Blackmagic of the UNIX". Check the website for more info about this library https://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/

Comment: FDs 0, 1 and 2 are already open in the child process. The `ancil_recv_fds` func is not expected to close the existing FDs so it uses another 2 new FDs.

Comment: thanks, it is ture. I get it.